# what is the transmission power value in dbm (min to max) -CC2420 RADIO

Tags: radio-transmission

within module implementation, to set  transmission power for the packet is 0 to 31 (min to max).

Actually what is the transmission power value??
    the range of transmission power in dbm???

```
31----  0 dbm
29 --- ??
28--- ??
7-----  -15dbm
0----  ??

Is 0dbm  the maximum transmission power value??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CC2420 datasheet give these values:

```
PA_LEVEL  Output power[dBm]  
   31            0
   27           -1
   23           -3
   19           -5
   15           -7
   11          -10
    7          -15
    3          -25
```

The datasheet can be downloaded from http://www.ti.com/product/cc2420

0 dBm is the maximum transmission power.